# Failed to read cluster ca certificate when joining worker node

Tags: kubernetes, ca, debian-buster, k0s

I am attempting to setup a multi-node k8s cluster as per this [kOS Setup Link](https://techviewleo.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-debian-using-k0s/), but I  face the error below when I try to join one of the nodes to the master node:

```
    k0s token create --role=worker
    WARN[2022-01-12 13:55:31] no config file given, using defaults
    Error: failed to read cluster ca certificate from /var/lib/k0s/pki/ca.crt: open 
    /var/lib/k0s/pki/ca.crt: no such file or directory. check if the control plane is 
    initialized on this node
```

I verified from the control node that this file does, exist however:

```
cd /var/lib/k0s/pki
ls
```

I am new to k8s setup from scratch, and a bit unsure which configuration item I need to fix (and where between master and worker nodes?).
My research shows that ***A token is required when joining a new worker node to the Kubernetes cluster -- This token is generated from the control node***. It also says that ***When you bootstrap a cluster with kubeadm, a token is generated which expires after 24 hours***

When I try to check for the existence of a token on master node I get:

```
 kubeadm tokens list
-bash: kubeadm: command not found
```

I am unsure however if this is correct ( Is k0s ***even*** bootstrapped with `kubeadm`??).

However using k0s CLI syntax I can see that they are no tokens on the master:

```
k0s token list
No k0s join tokens found
```

My question:

1. What do I need to do for the file that is reporting as missing.
2. Is this error (possibly) related to the issue of token above and if so do I first need to regenerate the token at the master node end.
3. I have encountered multiple fixes at this [Github Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53889) but I am not sure if any of them applies to my issue. Last thing I need is to break the current setup before I have even finished the cluster setup.

Environment
Master node : Debian 10 Buster
Worker node : Debian 10 Buster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same error as you when I tried to run `k0s token create --role=worker` on the **worker** node.

You need to run [this command on the **master** node](https://techviewleo.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-debian-using-k0s/):

> Next, you need to **create a join token** that the worker node will use to join the cluster. This token is generated from the control node.

First you need to run `k0s token create --role=worker` on the **master** node to get a token and later [use this token on the **worker** node](https://techviewleo.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-debian-using-k0s/):

> On the worker node, issue the command below.
>
> ```
> k0s worker <login-token>
> ```

So:

- generate a token on the **master** using `k0s token create --role=worker`
- use this token on the **worker** using `k0s worker <login-token>`

In my case I also needed to add `sudo` before both commands, so they looked like `sudo k0s token create --role=worker` and `sudo k0s worker <login-token>`

You wrote:

> I am unsure however if this is correct ( Is k0s ***even*** bootstrapped with kubeadm ?? ).

No, they are two different and independent solutions.